# What legal framework entitles Alex Stein to speak for 3 minutes and what are the parameters of this entitlement?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech

See this video: https://www.instagram.com/reel/CwDnEVAIE6z/

Comedian Alex stein uses public government meetings in his typical style to express controversial viewpoints through absurdist comedic quips.

Question in title.

Comment: Probably a good idea to at least try to understand how governmental public meetings work first. A basic "who can speak at city council meetings" google gets you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Governmental Bodies like a City Council often have an agenda item for "Public Comments" in their meetings.   This is often not required by any specific law, but is customary and important to enable members of the public to address concerns that might be of importance to the Council.

Once they create such a space in their meetings, it is largely protected by the First Amendment and the legal frameworks that have grown around it. **A governmental body cannot place a content-based prior restraint on the free speech.**

Often, there are some rules that ensure a bare minimum level of decorum at a public meeting, such as "No Profanity", "No Yelling", and provisions that cover Slander, personal attacks and non-germane topics. But beyond that, members of the public that get on the agenda are allowed to address any topic at all they want.

Sometimes when the council has a particularly lengthy agenda, they forgo the public comment period.  But avoiding it for more than a few meetings often leads to accusations of ignoring constituents and being unresponsive elected officials.

At many City Council meetings, a few repeat visitors who are either angry or mentally ill are common fixtures.  They are generally tolerated as it only takes a few minutes of council time, but pays respect to the First Amendment and American senses of freedom and government accountability.  Rarely, but on some occasions, when a speaker is repeatedly too disruptive and offensive, [the council can take action](https://www.thestranger.com/slog/2022/04/22/71462974/how-to-get-banned-from-public-comment-at-seattle-city-council).

Comment: There's some internal inconsistency here. If council can't impose content based restrictions, how can they forbid discussion of non-germane topics? I believe the majority rule is actually that content-based restrictions are generally permissible, as long as they don't veer into viewpoint discrimination.

Comment: @bdb484:  Generally *after* hearing the speaker ramble on about "Space Aliens" (or whatever), the council decides its not a relevant topic.  That is not "prior restraint".  It is cutting off commentary before the full 3 minutes is up.

Comment: @abelenky Isn't that just doubling down on internal inconsistency? "Cutting off commentary" is basically the definition of a prior restraint, regardless of whether it's about space aliens or a zoning variance. Citing some actual laws on this topic would probably go a long way toward making this a more correct answer.